# caching- android webview does not load css properly from cache

Tags: android, css, caching, webview, android-webview

I've implemented webview with caching mechanism that loads the page from cache when device is offline. but strangely I get following behaviour.

whenever device is offline and app is loading page from cache it looks as expected :

[image]

But the next time when I open the webview for same page. It renders the page from cache without css :

[image]

The sequence is continued for other times.i.e First the expected page and the other time the page without css. I've tried to find solutions but failed to come up with any . Does anyone know the reason of the strange behaviour of the webview loading ?

My Layout file is :

```
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/webViewPlaceholder"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"></FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I've declared webview inside a framelayout:

```
  @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 try {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=21)    {
         WebView.enableSlowWholeDocumentDraw();
     }
     setContentView(R.layout.display_result);
     url = Uri.parse(getIntent().getStringExtra("Url"));

     initUI();
 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {
     Toast.makeText(DisplayResult.this, ""+e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
}


public void initUI()
{
try {
    webViewPlaceholder = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.webViewPlaceholder);
    if (webView == null) {

        //webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView = new WebView(this);


        // webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);

        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize( 5 * 1024 * 1024 ); // 5MB
        webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath());
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL);
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT );

        webView.getSettings().setTextSize(WebSettings.TextSize.NORMAL);
        webView.getSettings().setTextZoom(0);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new Callback());

        if(!isConnectedToInternet())
        {

            webView.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK );

        }
        try {
            webView.loadUrl(url.toString());

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(DisplayResult.this,""+e,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    webViewPlaceholder.addView(webView);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Toast.makeText(DisplayResult.this, ""+e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}

private class Callback extends WebViewClient {
    MaterialDialog m=null ;


    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap facIcon) {

        //Toast.makeText(DisplayResult.this,"onload "+ (i++),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if(flag && m==null) {

            m = new MaterialDialog.Builder(DisplayResult.this)
                    .title("Fetching Result")
                    .content("Please wait...")
                    .progress(true, 0)

                    .show();


        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
        super.onPageFinished(view,url);
        //Toast.makeText(DisplayResult.this,"onfinish",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(flag || m!=null) {
            m.cancel();
            //Toast.makeText(DisplayResult.this, "canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        i=1;

    }
@Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        try {
            //Toast.makeText(DisplayResult.this,"onerror",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            new MaterialDialog.Builder(DisplayResult.this)
                    .title("Error ")
                    .content("No Internet Access")
                    .positiveText("OK")
                    .show();

            if (errorCode == -2) {

                String summary = "<html><body ><p style='color: red;'>Unable to load information. Please check if your network connection is working properly or try again later.</p></body></html>";
                view.loadData(summary, "text/html", null);


            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(DisplayResult.this, ""+e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


}
```

Targetsdkversion of my app is 21. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: did you try to debug your webview using chrome://inspect using chrome, check if css was loading properly?

Comment: @hars I tried that but was unable to find the reason of wierd behaviour.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I have the exactly same problem....:(